# no result response from FCM push notification

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We launched a new mobile app for iOS and Android devices first week of January and use FCM to send push notification to users.

Thus far we've sent (based on the firebase console report) ~60k notifications out to our users and overall its a very solid and reliable platform.  We split our 'sends' in groups of 1000 push tokens / devices.

Question:  ~15 times since we've launched we've received 'No Result' back from the CURL that sends the notifications upstream to FCM... and on one occasion we received an error 500.

To work around this and not just assume success we are detecting when the result isn't what we expect it to be upon success, and we log the response (i.e. "no result")... then wait 5 seconds and retry, up to 3 times.  (our log message denotes the 'try number' as well).

We have, maybe  twice a week, received the 'first try' message (meaning the first attempt failed and 5 secs later the 2nd attempt kicks off)... and only ONCE (this week) have we received the 'second try' message...

We're wondering if this is normal behavior for FCM?  Is there some paid level of support or access that would alleviate these re-try instances for us?   I don't think there is an SLA for FCM, but generally speaking are others seeing this same behavior and is the rate I've described here what you'd' consider 'normal'?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer received](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/u-yoWjlxjUw) from Google today:

Hello!

If I've correctly understood this, you have sent 60k messages and received 16 failures? That comes out to around 99.9997% success.  Three nines is pretty much industry gold. So looking stellar so far.

There is no paid FCM version, but all clients, regardless of payment plan, run on the best hardware available so you're already in the premium servers. : )